# asp.net-mvc-4 how to reference dynamically an item in a resource language file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know if we can do something like in codeigniter's view

codeigniter

```
<?
$parent_id = "nav_" . $parent[0];
echo "<span>".lang($parent_id)."</span>";
?>
```

asp.net-mvc-4

```
@{
string parentId = "nav_" + parent[0];
<span>@Resources.Language. ???   </span>
}
```

Dynamically reference an item in a resource file, is it possible in asp.net mvc?